# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline' while trying to compare two string variables

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm trying to tally the number of instances of a top level domain occur in a file containing 800K+ top level domain strings that I scraped from URLs. In the code below, when I used "if mstlds in ntld:" the results appeared to be correct but upon inspection "co" and "com", "ca" and "cat" counts are incorrect. But if I use == or "is" I don't get any matches at all but instead an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checktlds4malware.py", line 111, in 
    mtlds_line = mtlds.readline()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

```
tld_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
tld_line = tld_file.readline()
while tld_line:
    #print(tld_line)
    tld_line = tld_line.strip()
    columns = tld_line.split()
    ntld = columns[0]           # get the ICANN TLD
    ntld = ntld.lower()

    mtlds = open ('malwaretlds.txt', 'r')
    mtlds_line = mtlds.readline()
    while mtlds_line:
       print(mtlds_line)
       mtlds_line = mtlds_line.strip()
       columns = mtlds_line.split()
       mtlds = columns[0]
       mtlds = mtlds.lower()
       #raw_input()
       # I don't get the error when using "in" not ==
       # but the comparison is not correct.
       if mtlds_line == ntld:     
          m_count += 1
          print 'ntld and mtld match: Malware domain count for ', ntld, m_count
       mtlds_line = mtlds.readline()
    print 'Final malware domain count for ', ntld, m_count
```

Comment: What does `mltds` stand for? It points to a file object when you do `mtlds = open ('malwaretlds.txt', 'r')`, but inside the loop you do `mtlds = columns[0]`, so it then points to a string. What should it be? A file or a string? You should pick one type and stick to it.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. Let me try to correct this.

Comment: Yep, I should have used a different label like "mtld" for the string and mtlds for the file object. Works now, really appreciate the eyeball, feel kinda foolish that I couldn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because within your while loop, you are setting `mtlds` to be a String. Thus, once you attempt to use the `readline()` method you throw the error (pretty self explanatory). You have to remember that only outside the scope of your interior `while` loop is `mtlds` pointing to a file.